# Cannot install Wacom Intuos CTH 490 drivers

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 15.10, tablet, wacom

Why I cant install my Intuos Art drivers? I follow the instructions from the oficial [linuxwacom web](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom)
But i always get stuck

```
rodrigo@rodrigo-K54C:~$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm trying to draw something using Gimp, I have already installed the software, but It doesn't recognise my tablet. What can I do?
Thanks for everything :)

Comment: Did you do the `cd input-wacom-whatever` command in that tutorial? What you have shown there tells me that you are currently in your user directory and _not_ in the source directory.

Comment: I dont really know if i am doing it right... but it said
`bash: cd: xf86-input-wacom-0.32.0.tar.bz2: Not a directory
`
All in all Thanks for your help mate

Comment: `cd` is for directories. It tells the terminal the directory you want to work from. `./` means "take this file/folder from the current working directory." You need to extract that `tar.bz2` file, which is shown under the "Download" section of that tutorial. Follow the whole thing and you should be fine.

Comment: Oh god! Thanks I think i've got it, but the problem now, is this one
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
`

Comment: So you `cd`ed in, ran `./configure` and then ran just `make`, with nothing before or after?

Comment: Right, just before `./configure ` i used `make` but it gives me that error.

Comment: You want to use it after you run `./configure`

Comment: Just like it's shown in the tutorial

Comment: Okay, true, but the error stills :(
thank you so much for your help ^^

Comment: Did `./configure` throw any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33448/discussion-between-rodrigo-jimenez-angulo-and-zacharee1).